# how to avoid "Unresolved attribute reference"

Tags: python, pycharm

The following code works fine but gives a warning in PyCharm as follows:

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'join' for class 'int':16
```

I understand what the warning is and why it's occurring, but I wonder if there's a better way to do this to remove the warning. If I could 'type' ss for example so the IDE would understand what's happening. Normally the thread code is in another module and is accessed by main and I'd rather main didn't have to know anything about 'ss.'

```py
import time
import threading

ss=0
keepgoing=True

def fstart():
    global keepgoing, ss
    ss=threading.Thread(target=tmod)
    ss.start()
    keepgoing=True

def fstop():
    global keepgoing
    keepgoing=False
    ss.join()

def tmod():
    x=0
    while keepgoing:
        time.sleep(2)
        print(str(x))
        x+=1
        if x==10 : x=0

def main():
    print('Start')
    fstart()
    time.sleep(15)
    fstop()
    print('Done')

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a warning because you define `ss` to be an integer by setting it to `0` at the top. You can turn it off by using the correct type hint. Replace the following line:

```py
ss=0
```

with

```py
ss: threading.Thread
```

Comment: I'm running PyCharm 2023.3.2. Changed the one line of code "ss=0" to "ss=threading.Thread." One warning went away and the other warning appeared.

Comment: Look carefully, it's a `:`, not an `=`.

Comment: Oh yes I did it wrong. Changed it and everything OK. Thanks.

Comment: All good. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html for further reading if you are interested.